# Not able to update data of ParseUser class in Unity3D using Javascript

Tags: unity-game-engine, parse-platform, unityscript

I am using this code to update data of a Parse User, but the data is not updating nor am I able to retrieve the data.

I am able to do update and retrieve the data for a ParseObject class created by me. Can someone tell me where I am wrong on this?

Out of all the debugs I have set I am able to see only the 1st debug "parse GetSync function passed" and the rest are not printing.

```js
var parseUser: ParseUser;

function FBtoParse(){
    var query = ParseUser.Query;
    query.GetAsync("Q0D9eBvRee").ContinueWith(GetSync);
    Debug.Log("parse GetSync function passed");
    Debug.Log("Object ID: "+ parseUser["objectId"]);
    Debug.Log("username is : "+ parseUser["username"]);
    Debug.Log("User Updated");
}

var GetSync = function (t:System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<ParseUser>){

    parseUser = t.Result;
};

function OnGUI{

    if (GUILayout.Button("Parse"))
    {
        FBtoParse();
        Debug.Log("Pressed Parse");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear in this code where the user is actually being updated. Also, you can always get the currentUser from ParseUser currentUser, without needing to query for it.

Comment: What does ParseUser look like?  It looks like you're accessing values in `parseUser` using a string indexer.  Does `parseUser["objectId"]` even exist because it isn't apparent in your code when `parseUser` is set and filled.

Answer (score 0):

Parse at the moment only allows ParseUsers to update their own object through authentication.

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-security-for-user-objects